# Error when reusing Google SpreadSheet Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

The Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(1*('Test Cases'! $G$3:$G <> ""), 1*('Test Cases'! $I$3:$I <> ""), 1*('Test Cases'! $J$3:$J<>"")))
```

Works in Google Spreadsheet, but gives error in Excel.

I tried removing `=ARRAYFORMULA` but I still get an error

Comment: In Excel, you need a row argument for the 2nd half of `$I$3:$I`, e.g., `$I$3:$I23`. I'd also get rid of the spaces after the `!`s.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2007 or later COUNTIFS would probably be the best option, e.g.

`=COUNTIFS('Test Cases'!$G$3:$G$1000,"<>",'Test Cases'!$I$3:$I$1000,"<>",'Test Cases'!$J$3:$J$1000,"<>")`

Answer (score 2):

If you need a formula that will work in both Google Sheets and Excel, you can use a trick where a dummy INDEX function will enable array calculations in Sheets, but won't break the formula in Excel:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1*('Test Cases'!$G$3:$G$1000<>""),1*('Test Cases'!$I$3:$I$1000<>""),1*('Test Cases'! $J$3:$J$1000<>""))+INDEX(0,1)`